# Split DataFrameGroupBy into individual frames (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have grouped following DF by `host` and `operation` columns:

```
df
Out[163]:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 100 entries, 10069 to 1003
Data columns (total 8 columns):
args             100  non-null values
host             100  non-null values
kwargs           100  non-null values
log_timestamp    100  non-null values
operation        100  non-null values
thingy             100  non-null values
status           100  non-null values
time             100  non-null values
dtypes: float64(1), int64(2), object(5)


g = df.groupby(['host','operation'])

g
Out[165]: <pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7f46ec731890>

g.groups.keys()[:10]
Out[166]:
[('yy39.segm1.org', 'gtfull'),
 ('yy39.segm1.org', 'updateWidg'),
 ('yy36.segm1.org', 'notifyTestsDelivered'),
 ('yy32.segm1.org', 'notifyTestsDelivered'),
 ('yy20.segm1.org', 'gSettings'),
 ('yy32.segm1.org', 'x_gWidgboxParams'),
 ('yy39.segm1.org', 'clearElems'),
 ('yy3.segm1.org', 'gxyzinf'),
 ('yy34.segm1.org', 'setFlagsOneWidg'),
 ('yy13.segm1.org', 'x_gbinf')]
```

Now I need to get individual DataFrames for each ('host', 'operation') pair. I can do it by iterating over groups keys:

```
for el in g.groups.keys():
     ...:     print el, 'VALUES', g.groups[el]
     ...:
('yy25.segm1.org', 'x_gbinf') VALUES [10021]
('yy36.segm1.org', 'gxyzinf') VALUES [10074, 10085]
('yy25.segm1.org', 'updateWidg') VALUES [10022]
('yy25.segm1.org', 'gtfull') VALUES [10019]
('yy16.segm1.org', 'gxyzinf') VALUES [10052, 10055, 10062, 10064]
('yy32.segm1.org', 'addWidging2') VALUES [10034]
('yy16.segm1.org', 'notifyTestsDelivered') VALUES [10056, 10065]
```

Questions:

Q1. I'm wondering if I should split the `DataFrameGroupBy` object or is there a faster way of achieving the goal here?

Strategically: I need to calculate exponential weighted moving average and exponential weighted standard deviation (although std dev should be attenuated much more slowly).

To this end, I need have it:

a. grouped by host, operation

b. each host/operation subset sorted by log_timestamp

c. ewma and ewmstd calculated for `time` column.

Is there a way of achieving this without splitting `DataFrameGroupBy`?

Q2. The goal is to signal when particular time for host/operation becomes abnormal in the last several minutes (overload condition). I've had an idea that if I calculate 'slow ewmstd' and 'slow ewma' (for longer period of time, say, 1 hr) then the short-term ewma (say 5 minutes) could be interpreted as emergency value if it's more than 2 slow std deviations from the slow ewma (three sigma rule). I'm not even sure if this is correct / best approach. Is it?

It may be, since this is roughly similar to how UNIX 1m, 5m, and 15m load averages work: if 15m is normal but 1m load avg is much higher, you know that the load has been much higher than usual. But I'm not sure of that.

Comment: read here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html, you just need to ``df.groupby(['host','operation']).apply(lambda x: do your calc on x)``.

Comment: if you make it an answer, I'll check it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

docs are [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)

you just need to:

```
def f(x):
     return a calculation on x

f can also be lambda x: ....

df.groupby(['host','operation']).apply(f)
```

Comment: One thing that was news to me: `x` up there is a full blown Pandas object (usually a DataFrame, sometimes a Series, depends on context).  So you can do all sorts of useful stuff to `x` within `f`.  For example: `x['newcol'] = super_awesome_function(x)` works fine.  As does something like `x['movavg'] = pd.rolling_mean(x, periods=20)`.  So you can use `f` to tack a few more columns onto `x` and then, ultimately, just `return x`.

Comment: groupby is very powerful. you can do quite complicated types of ops with it. however, sometimes it makese sense to use the vectorized on the whole frame, either before after a groupby (as a groupby is essentially a looped operation).

Comment: in general it IS faster to return a new object (and not to modify the current object); this is the slow/fast path stuff.